# Display in existing window without sidebar option for the javascript button

Tags: javascript, button

I have implemented the code in the JavaScript list button. the problem is when we click that button form the listview pop, the page is open with in that popup. so how to avoid that. see the below image.

[image]

**Javascript Code:**

```
if ('{!$User.LastName}' == 'TestUser'){
  window.location.href = '/{!Quote.Id}';
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the javascript code you are using for the button?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question, what behavior do you want when the user clicks your custom button? Open a pop-up? Navigate the browser to that page?

Comment: @DougAyers I have add My button in the account related list layout. it is show fine and if we click that button the record is open. but the problem is when i click the button from the relatedlist popup like above image, the record is open within that popup. so i have to resolve that issue.

Comment: To make sure I understand, your user starts in the main browser window. They click your custom button which is on a related list. The custom button opens a new popup window with your visualforce page. On the visualforce page inside the popup window your user clicks a button and that loads new content inside the popup window but you want to load it in the main browser window? That may be a bit more tricky...

Answer (score 2):

To have a visualforce page **not** display the **sidebar** or **header** then you can turn those off when defining your `<apex:page>` ([documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm)).

For example, in your `VFSamplePage` you may need to change the declaration to:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false"> ... </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window.open method with target location. For e.g.:-
window.open("http://www.google.com","_top");

Comment: Anshul, if you aren't sure, it may be better to post as a comment. As this looks like a valid answer I've reworded it a bit for you.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke : The code i've provided would open the new window in the browser window and no the little inline popup screen from quicklinks. BTW.. thanks for the edits.

Comment: @Lemon: Have I understood the problem correctly?